# c# How to check object property and convert it proper way?

Tags: c#

I have a code

Page.cs

```
public class Page
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public String Title { get; set; }
        public String SubTitle { get; set; }
        public String Slug { get; set; }
        public String Content { get; set; }
        public Int16 Status { get; set; }
        public Int16 Visibility { get; set; }
        public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }
        public int Order { get; set; }
        public byte[] FeaturedImage { get; set; }
        public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public Guid ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

Other.cs

```
Some.Insert(new Page
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Title = "Glass",
            SubTitle = "",
            Slug = "glass",
            Content = "content",
            Status = 1,
            Visibility = 1,
            ParentId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Order = 1,
            FeaturedImage = null,
            CreatedBy = Guid.NewGuid(),
            CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
            ModifiedBy = Guid.NewGuid(),
            ModifiedAt = DateTime.Now
        });
```

Some.cs

```
public static void Insert(Object insertObject)
        {
    Type myType = insertObject.GetType();
    IList < PropertyInfo > props = new List < PropertyInfo > (myType.GetProperties());
    foreach(PropertyInfo prop in props)
    {
        Object val = prop.GetValue(insertObject, null);
            if (prop.PropertyType.Name == "Byte[]")
            {
                values.Add(new SqlParameter(prop.Name, Convert.ToByte(val)));
            } 
            else
                values.Add(new SqlParameter(prop.Name, val));
    }

}
```

my code show that, i hard code check every propertyType and name, convert it after that. its really tired, how to convert object to origin datatype proper way.

What I want achieve is create a data access object dynamically.
I always get error when upload picture, convert to byte[], and finally i get an error cant convert string to varbinary(max).
Thats why i add :

```
if (prop.PropertyType.Name == "Byte[]")
                {
                    values.Add(new SqlParameter(prop.Name, Convert.ToByte(val)));
                }
```

i think this is not a solution, that's why i ask the proper way.

Comment: I can't see what your code is actually trying to achieve? Sounds a little like an XY problem but can't be sure..

Comment: `Convert.ChangeType(val, prop.PropertyType.Name)` would work here. Where is returned data being used after conversion?

Comment: i get error : Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Type' , because prop.Property.Name return String

Comment: What exactly are you inserting? Does the parameter type really need to be `Object`?

Comment: @yozawiratama sorry remove Name `Convert.ChangeType(val, prop.PropertyType)`

Comment: in my opinion, better to use the generic approach, Insert<T>( T item)

Comment: @HadiHassan I Follow your opinion, its works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve but you can replace your `Insert` method with:

```
public static void Insert(object insertObject)
{
    var convertedObject = Convert.ChangeType(insertObject, insertObject.GetType());
}
```